# Generate big an array from a few words

Tags: javascript, array

I need to generate a huge array from a few words, and not random, I must get the same array always for the same words.

I wrote this code which will generate 3050 from 51 letters, but I'm sure there is a better way to do it.

The idea is to convert the letters to ASCII numbers and put them into an array, then manipulate this array to get a new big array.

````
this.otpOne = 'OrangePie'
this.otpTwo = 'ClearBlueSky'
this.otpThree = 'RedApplePie'
this.otpFour = 'MakeItEasy'
this.otpFive = 'blueBerry'

gen();

function gen() {
    let otpString = this.otpOne + this.otpTwo + this.otpThree + this.otpFour + this.otpFive;
    let otpStringArray = otpString.split('').map(char => char.charCodeAt(0));
    let otpStringSorted = otpStringArray.sort();
    let median = this.median(otpStringSorted);
    Array.prototype.swap = function () {
        let len = this.length;
        let d = [];
        for (let y = 0; y < len; y++) {
            if (y + 1 < len) {
                let tempOne = this[y];
                let tempTwo = this[y + 1];
                d.push(tempTwo, tempOne);
                tempOne = '';
                tempTwo = '';
            }
        }
        return d;
    };

    let left = [], right = [], odd = [], even = [];
    odd.push(otpStringSorted.filter(num => Math.abs(num) % 2 === 1));
    even.push(otpStringSorted.filter(num => Math.abs(num) % 2 === 0));
    right.push(otpStringSorted.filter(num => Math.abs(num) > median));
    left.push(otpStringSorted.filter(num => Math.abs(num) < median));
    let chunksOne = this.makeChunks(otpStringSorted, 2);
    let chunksTwo = this.makeChunks(otpStringSorted, 3);
    let chunksThree = this.makeChunks(otpStringSorted, 4);
    let chunksFour = this.makeChunks(odd.concat(right).flat(), 2);
    let chunksFive = this.makeChunks(even.concat(left).flat(), 2);
    let otpStringSortedRev = Array.from(otpStringSorted).reverse();
    let stringsArraysV1 = [
        ...odd.flat(),
        ...left.flat(),
        ...even.flat(),
        ...right.flat(),
        ...chunksOne.flat(),
        ...chunksTwo.flat(),
        ...chunksThree.flat(),
        ...chunksFour.flat(),
        ...chunksFive.flat(),
        ...otpStringSortedRev.flat()];
    let stringsArraysV2 = [
        ...even.flat(),
        ...right.flat(),
        ...odd.flat(),
        ...even.flat(),
        ...chunksFive.flat(),
        ...chunksFour.flat(),
        ...chunksThree.flat(),
        ...chunksTwo.flat(),
        ...chunksOne.flat(),
        ...otpStringSortedRev.flat()];
    let stringsArraysV3 = stringsArraysV1.filter(num => Math.abs(num) % 2 === 1 ? num / 2 : num)
    let stringsArraysV4 = stringsArraysV2.filter(num => Math.abs(num) % 2 === 1 ? num / 2 : num)
    this.stringsArrays = [
        ...stringsArraysV1,
        ...stringsArraysV2,
        ...stringsArraysV3,
        ...stringsArraysV4,
        ...otpStringSorted.swap(),
        ...stringsArraysV1.swap(),
        ...stringsArraysV2.swap(),
        ...stringsArraysV3.swap(),
        ...stringsArraysV4.swap(),
    ];

    $('.key').text(this.stringsArrays)
    $('.len').text('len: ' + otpString.length + ' to ' + this.stringsArrays.length)

}



function makeChunks(array, size) {
    let add = (a, b) => a + b,
        newArray = [],
        i = 0;
    while (i < array.length) {
        newArray.push(array.slice(i, i += size).reduce(add) % (33 - 126));
    }
    let finalArray = newArray.map(num => num < 34 ? ((92 - num) + num) : num);

    return finalArray;
}

function median(values) {
    values.sort(function (a, b) {
        return a - b;
    });
    let half = Math.floor(values.length / 2);

    if (values.length % 2)
        return values[half];
    else
        return (values[half - 1] + values[half]) / 2.0;
}
```
````

Comment: what's the big array requirement? element length? uniqueness? Will the big array be sorted?

Comment: no specific requirement, but it should be created again when needed, as big as can be, no need to be sorted, and it will not be unique.

Comment: if you don't have any requirement, you can just use all letters in those string and split them into an array, you can create a bigger array by manipulate permutation, subsequence, etc from the string array. I think you can generate way more than 3050 results from 51 letters. Your code seems make an easy problem complex

Comment: No problem, but this won't overload the user browser? this is how I know to increase the size, would suggest a better way or do you have additional code may increase the size, or maybe more simple way.

Comment: I mean if you don't have any requirement, can you use a loop to generate an array with all the same string in it and you can pick any size you want? It won't overload user browser. Your code seems too complex and may be overloaded with all those built in functions

Comment: Well, then I will search how to array permutation. Thanks.